# Function not modifying passed parameter value

Tags: javascript, validation

I have the following function:

```
function validateField(target, field, field_check) {
            if(target.val().trim().length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo $html->url('/fonykers/validate_',true); ?>'+ field + '/' + target.val(), 
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(response) {
                        if(!response.ok) {
                            if(target.is('.ok')) {
                                target.removeClass('ok');
                            }
                            target.addClass('error');
                            error.html(response.msg);
                            error.fadeIn();
                            field_check = false;
                        } else {
                            if(target.is('.error')) {
                                target.removeClass('error');
                            }
                            target.addClass('ok');
                            alert('voy a asignar true');
                            field_check = true;
                        }
                    },
                        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                            alert(xhr.statusText);
                            alert(thrownError);
                            field_check = false;
                        } 
                });        
            } else {
                error.html('You must specify a ' + field);
                error.fadeIn();
                target.addClass('error');
                field_check = false;
            } 

        }
```

I use it to validate my form input fields, the target variable es the field itself, for instance: `$('#name_field')` the 2nd variable es a string specifying the name of the field for instance `name` as to know what PHP function it's gonna call. The last is a boolean that I use to know wether or now the field is valid or not for instance `name_check` which I define at the beginning of the scripta and set to false.

My problem is that `field_check` gets changed in the local scope properly but it never modifies que external variable that has been passed in, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: With prototype, you would need to add .bind(this) to the error callback. Maybe this helps finding a solution, I don't know jQuery.

Comment: The weird thing is that the field is modified properly, but it won't change a simple boolean

Comment: Where are you defining field_check? Is it a global varaible? Alternately you can stash this value in .data() or in the value of a hidden DIV or field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive variables (int / boolean / etc) are passed to functions by value - that is, when someone passes one of them to a function, the value of the variable is passed to your function, not the variable itself.  What you're modifying is in fact a different variable altogether.

The easiest solution is to just return true or false when you've finished validating the field, and use the function's return value instead of checking `field_check`.

You can also do a couple different things with globals / properties.  For instance...

```
var validator = function (target, field) {
  ...
  this.field_check = false;
}

validator(target, field);
if (validator.field_check) {
  ...
}
```

Note the use of `this.field_check` and the assignment of the function to a variable

Comment: Thank you, Sam, great explanation. The thing is I tried returning the value in the success part but it always left the variable as undefined, I'll give it another try, maybe I was doing something wrong before.

Comment: Question, where do you declare the field_check? I'm declaring it at the start of the function but when I go to check it I get undefined

Comment: Declaring it at the start should be fine, just make sure you always refer to it inside the function as this.field_check

Comment: Did that but I think I'm not understanding something about the AJAX call or something because y

Comment: Must be missing something because I can't access the variable in an external scope, and seems it's not getting set in the AJAX call. I still can't access it with it saying undefined in the outer scope even if I give it a value starting the function.

Comment: Bah, sorry, need to test these things first... Thought saving the function in a variable would let you use the `this` keyword; anyway, take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/A2UCL/

Comment: Ok, that worked, thanks Sam. Now any idea how I can manage that with AJAX validations? The problem with them being that the value is set after the call is complete so if I set the validate.field_check to another variable right after the execution of the function it will not hold the real value of the validation.

Comment: You can set the option `async:false` for the ajax request, which will delay execution of your javascript thread until the request finishes.  The downside is that if you're sending out a request for each field, you may notice a substantial decrease in speed.  The other way to do it would be to put the code which processes the form validation result in your ajax success handler.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the variables are not passed by reference. You can either have that as a return value or use a workaround like this: http://sirdarckcat.blogspot.com/2007/07/passing-reference-to-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript simple types are always passed by value, never by reference. In other words you are passing a copy of the boolean value. The copy gets changes, but the original never will.

Your validate field function will need to either return the new value, or expect a callback function that will receive it. You have to explicitly set the new value to the original variable.